# Будут ли проблемы если не использовать точку с запятой в javascript?

Tags: javascript, синтаксис

Был бы рад примеру, если ответ на мой вопрос будет положительным. На данный момент я не видел ни одного случая использования этого знака, где его нельзя было бы просто пропустить. Интерпретатор тоже ни разу не выдавал ошибки из-за отсустствия точки с запятой.

Comment: Существуют цепочки вида `Promise(...)[новая строка].then(...)[новая строка].then(...)`, в которых точки с запятой ставить нельзя, поэтому для различия подобных ситуаций точки с запятой там, где можно ставить, лучше всё-таки ставить

Comment: Есть разные code style, где то их предлагают ставить, а где то нет.
Но я знаю что интерпретатор ругается, если перед IIFE не поставить точку с запятой

Answer (score 14, accepted):

В цикле for нельзя пропустить.

```
for(объявление переменных; условие; обновление счетчика)
```

А так же если вы хотите сделать пустое тело цикла:

```
while(true);
console.log(1) // Без точки с запятой это попадёт в тело цикла
```

Еще один кейс, при присваивании без точки с запятой в конце можно прихватить что нибудь лишнее, например выражение в скобках может быть понято как вызов функции:

```js
const i = 0
(2+1).toString();
```

Или например можно потерять regex:

```js
const i = 0
/[a-z]/g.exec(i)
```

или вы хотите сделать массив, а интерпретатор может подумать, что вы хотите достать из конца предыдущей строки какое-то свойство:

```js
console.log(2)
[1,2].map(num => num*2);
```

Можно еще придумать кейс, когда унарный плюс превращается без точки с запятой в сложение

Comment: Есть styleguide's заставляющие ставить ; как раз перед массивом/скобками и т.п. =)

Answer (score 6):

Проблемы будут в том случае, если новый statement (написанный на новой строке) должен начинаться с одного из следующих символов: `[` (массив), `(` (скобка), `` ` `` (шаблонная строка), `/` (регулярка), `+`, `-` (унарные плюс и минус).

Если точку с запятой принято не ставить, то её обычно добавляют перед этими конструкциями. Другой вариант - добавлять ключевое слово `void`, правда, он менее универсален.

Answer (score 5):

В JS есть автоподстановка `;`.
Но она [*может* приводить к ошибкам](https://learn.javascript.ru/structure#semicolon).

Например:

```js
function test () {
  return {answer: 42}; // (2) Всё ОК
}

function test2 () {
  return               // (3) А тут — нет! А разница только в переносе строки
  {answer: 43};        // А всё из-за того, что автоподставлятор ; поставил конец выражения возврата после перевода строки, выполнил return (без аргумента возвращает undefined), а после него вообще ничего не выполняется
}

console.info(test(), test2()); // (1) Выводит {answer: 42} undefined. Почему?
```

Поэтому лучше всегда ставить.
Это не сложно, когда привыкнешь, зато в коде будет больше ясности.

Comment: Каким образом правило ставить семиколоны избавит меня от необходимости начинать возвращаемое выражение на той же строке? Имхо, это две разные беды.

Comment: @vp_arth, Боюсь, я не совсем Вас понял. Принуждать Вас будет автоподставка `;`, иначе ситуация в `test2` могла бы вернуть объект.

Comment: Ок. "лучше всегда ставить". Куда мне поставить точку с запятой во втором примере, чтобы оно заработало?

Comment: Эммм... Там, где она стоит сейчас? Я думал "всегда ставить" - это не бездумное тыкание везде, а по правилам, но, видимо, это не слишком очевидно оказалось.

Comment: Там, где она стоит сейчас не поможет, вернётся undefined.

Answer (score 4):

Когда вы сцепляете куски JavaScript кода для выполнения в функцию [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) вам обязательно надо ставить `;`  в конце выражения к которому сцепляется другой код. Вот пример

```js
var x = 10, y = 20;
var res = eval("var z = x * y;"+"z = z + 1") + "<br>"; 
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Что произойдет если этого не сделать?

Comment: Интерпретатор будет выполнять `eval()`, который получился после сцепления и выдаст ошибку.

Comment: А если вместо `;` таки добавить `\n`?

Comment: в данном примере это сработает, но идея остается той же самой, при сцеплении вы не можете точно определить нужен вам `;` или нет. Поэтому чтобы избежать ошибок, то лучше его ставить.

Comment: Или таки добавлять его "при сцеплении". `['var a=1', 'a++'].join(';')`

Answer (score 3):

При такой формулировке, это вопрос вероятности ошибок при неопределенности условий (исходных данных), и логичный ответ на него: *«может будут, а может и нет»*. Он скорее для гадалок, чем для программистов :)

---

Если же рассмотреть вопрос с точки зрения норм и правил, а не в формулировке а-ля "когда я вернусь, выйдя из дома?" - обратимся к [спецификации ECMAScript](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-automatic-semicolon-insertion):

> **11.9 Automatic Semicolon Insertion**
>   Most ECMAScript statements and declarations *must* be terminated with a semicolon. Such semicolons *may* always appear explicitly in the source text. For convenience, however, such semicolons *may* be omitted from the source text in certain situations.

То есть, мы можем как ставить точки с запятой, так и надеяться на корректное выполнение кода не проставляя их - но большинство выражений JS **должно** завершаться `;` (интерпретатор "ставит их за нас", когда мы пропускаем).

Таким образом, вопрос сводится к тому, «является ли результат работы алгоритма автоматической вставки `;` ожидаемым в абсолютно любых возможных ситуациях?» - и ответ, очевидно: «**нет**, не является. А значит, проблемы из-за этого *возможны*».
Подтверждением тому, служит пример из спецификации:

> The source
>
> ```
> a = b + c
> (d + e).print()
> ```
>
> is not transformed by automatic semicolon insertion, because the parenthesized expression that begins the second line can be interpreted as an argument list for a function call:
>
> ```
> a = b + c(d + e).print()
> ```
>
> In the circumstance that an assignment statement must begin with a left parenthesis, *it is a good idea for the programmer to provide an explicit semicolon at the end of the preceding statement rather than to rely on automatic semicolon insertion.*

p.s.: В качестве вывода, выходящего за рамки вопроса, можно взять выделенное курсивом в последней цитате (то есть, ставить `;` не только в случаях подобных примеру, а всюду, где это синтаксически необходимо). Ну, или наоборот... простите за осуждающий тон - подчиниться лени и безответственности: "раз в стандарте написано что так можно, пусть машина дописывает за меня". Тут уж каждый решает сам.